# jquery ajax works only works in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have a bilangual MVC 3 application. I use a dropdownlist to change the language by saving the value of the dropdownlist into cookie and session. the problem is when I release it, it works only in IE. following is my code. note: the site will be reloaded and when I close firefox or chrome and reponed it,  the language has been changed but nothing happend if I dont close FF or chrome. thank you very much for your help.
I have used $.get, $.post every kind of combinations.

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#languagesDiv select').change(function () {
        var myvalue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            url: "/Language/SetLanguage",
            data: { code: myvalue },
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

        //             @*   $.post('@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language")', { code: $(this).val() },
        //                            function (result) {
        //                            }
        //                );*@

        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 21);

        $.cookie('MyData', $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: myDate });

        //window.location.reload();
        window.location.href = '/News/Index';
    });
});
```

C# code:

```
//tested with and without [httppost]
public void SetLanguage(string code)
{
    if (Session["MyCulture"] != null && Convert.ToString(Session["MyCulture"]) != code ) 
    {
        Session["MyCulture"] = code;
        HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["MyData"]; // new HttpCookie("MyData");
        aCookie.Value = code;
        //HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["LangCookie"];
        aCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
        //Response.AppendCookie(aCookie);
    }

    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");           
}
```

Thank you again.

Comment: Please format your questions properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see (there could be others with the backend) is that your AJAX request likely won't complete in the other/newer browsers.  When you call this:

```
window.location.href = '/News/Index';
```

...you're telling the browser to navigate away, this means it's *instantly* going there, regardless of whether that previous AJAX request completed (the browser will likely kill the request early and move on).

Instead, you should redirect *after* that request completes and do the re-direct in your `success` handler, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#languagesDiv select').change(function () {
    var myvalue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "xml",
      url: "/Language/SetLanguage",
      data: { code: myvalue },
      success: function (data) {
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 21);    
        $.cookie('MyData', $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: myDate });

        window.location.href = '/News/Index';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This way you're only telling the user to change pages after you've *successfully* made a request to change the language.